# Differentiation using r

Tags: r, derived, differentiation

I'm new to using R or any type of programming and I'm trying to differentiate 3xcos(xy) with respect to x. I've tried four different ways and was wondering which one is best/correct.

```
D(expression(3*x*cos(xy)),"x")
D(expression(3*x*cos*(xy)),"x")
D(expression(3*x*cos*(xy)),"x")
D(expression(3*x*cos*(x*y)),"x")
```

thanks in advance
Shane

Comment: Did you try any of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None of those.

This is the correct expression:

```
D(expression(3*x*cos(x*y)),"x")
#3 * cos(x * y) - 3 * x * (sin(x * y) * y)
```

This treats `xy` as one variable:

```
D(expression(3*x*cos(xy)),"x")
#3 * cos(xy)
```

This treats `xy` as one variable and `cos` as a variable (and not a function):

```
D(expression(3*x*cos*(xy)),"x")
#3 * cos * (xy)
```

This treats `cos` as a variable:

```
D(expression(3*x*cos*(x*y)),"x")
#3 * cos * (x * y) + 3 * x * cos * y
```

Comment: Thanks Roland, made perfect sense