# Differentiation using r studio

Tags: r

I'm new to using R or any type of programming and I'm trying to differentiate the equation below in R:

$x^{t} e^{t(1-x)}$

with respect to x. I've tried this method but R is showing me there is an unexpected symbol

D(expression((x^t)*exp^(t(1-x)),"x")

thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differentiation using r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26656879/differentiation-using-r)

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is a typo as there is no closing bracket on the call to the expression function.

There is an additional issue that the `t` term needs to be explicitly multiplied by `(1-x)`. This is discussed in more detail in the answers for [Differentiation using r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26656879/differentiation-using-r?rq=1).

I have produced the solution with these fixes below.

```r
#Reformatted code to show where the correction occurs
 
D(
  expression(
# Added "*" between t and (1- x)
    (x^t)*exp(t *(1-x))
# Added the closing bracket
  ),
  "x"
)
#> x^(t - 1) * t * exp^(t * (1 - x)) - (x^t) * (exp^(t * (1 - x)) * 
#>     (log(exp) * t))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: The circumflex in `exp^(t *(1-x))` is wrong, `exp()` doesn't need it.

Comment: Thanks I'll fix this I hadn't spotted that in the code